# Can we install ROS 1 and ROS 2 in the same system running on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-noetic, ubuntu-20.04

I am using ROS Noetic on my machine running on Ubuntu 20.04. But I want to migrate to ROS 2. Can I install ROS 2 along with ROS 1 on the same machine? If I did, what and how will be the causes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can install ROS and ROS 2 in the same system. Just make sure you source the right version of `setup.bash`:

```
source /opt/ros/<ros_distro>/setup.bash
```

Also, make sure to install the correct [ROS 2 distro](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Releases.html) for your ubuntu platform. In your case, that's `Foxy Fitzroy` (for Ubuntu 20.04).

If you install correctly, everything will be fine since all the relevant packages are installed at different locations.

ROS 1   `/opt/ros/noetic/`

ROS 2  `/opt/ros/foxy/` (EOL May 2023)

Comment: the EOL of ROS2 foxy is already has already passed. So, is it okay to go with ROS2 foxy or humble?

Comment: Yes, it's completely okay. You cannot also go for ROS 2 humble, but for that Ubuntu 22.04 is required. If you have to use ROS noetic, then just use foxy.

Comment: FYI, on Ubuntu 20.04, ROS G)alatic (also EOLed) is newer, meaning ROS' core components in G might be newer than those in F)oxy. But because Foxy as an LTS was alive longer than G, some non-core components might be newer in F.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

> Can we install ROS 1 and ROS 2 in the same system running on Ubuntu 20.04?

Yes.

Please use the following combinations:

- ROS 1: [Noetic Ninjemys](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu), [EOL: May 2025](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions)
- ROS 2: [Galactic Geochelone](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Installation.html), [**EOL: Dec, 2022**](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Releases.html)

It is important to be aware that the end-of-life (EOL) for ROS Galactic has already passed. This means that it is highly suggested to perform a major migration to a newer version of both ROS 2 and Ubuntu OS.

On the other hand, having ROS 1 and 2 on the same machine has no conflicts, as I have done in the past. Furthermore, the installation locations are different, such as the following:

1. /opt/ros/noetic
2. /opt/ros/galactic

Answer (score 0):

As you guys suggested, i installed both ROS-noetic and ROS1-foxy in the same machine. The thing is, i have to make sure the source of what i am using currently. i.e., if i am using noetic i should source my workspace as

```
source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
```

and if i am using foxy, i should source my workspace as

```
source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash
```